# ¿Cómo insertar datos serializados en una tabla de la base de datos PostgreSQL? - PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, serialización, insert

Necesito insertar datos serializados de un formulario en una tabla en datos *PostgreSQL*.

La siguiente imagen muestra el formulario y los datos a enviar.

[image: Formulario con datos a insertar.]

Los datos del formulario los serializo con *Javascript* y los envío por post a *PHP*, pero no logro insertarlos a la base de datos.

En el **script.js** hago esto:

```
var data = $("#" + formulario).serialize() + '&opcion=' + formulario;
$.post("salvar.php", data, function (data) {
    if (data == true) {
        console.log('ok');
    }
}
```

Los datos serializados que llegan al *PHP* son:

```
empleado=101&list_email=""
&empleado=102&list_email=""
&empleado=103&list_email=jj%40jj.com
&check_list%5B%5D=2
&check_list%5B%5D=3
&check_list%5B%5D=5
&check_list%5B%5D=6
&check_list%5B%5D=7
&opcion=formulario
```

En el *PHP* no sé cómo insertarlos a la base de datos, pero en él tengo este código:

**Nota:** En el *PHP* verifico que vengan los *CheckBox* para insertarlos en un solo registro.

Ejemplo: **Lunes es 1, martes es 2, domingo es 7**, y si no se ha seleccionado 
ningún día, coloco cero (0) y armo un string que quedaría así: `1200007`.

```
$opcion = $_POST['opcion'];

switch ($opcion) {
    case "formulario":

    if (isset($_REQUEST['check_list'])) {
        $optionArray = $_REQUEST['check_list'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($optionArray); $i++) {
            if ($optionArray[$i] == $i+1){
                $dias .= $optionArray[$i];
            }else{
                $dias .= 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si ya sabes que el 1 es Lunes, el 2 es martes y el 7 es domingo no te hace falta almacenar los 0s. Con que almacenes 127 te vale, es decir, con esa codificación solo necesitas guardar los dias que tienen check.

Answer (score 2):

si lo que no sabes como hacer una conexión, te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a este enlace, en el explican muy bien como realizar una conexión con PDO.

[Documentacion](https://www.uno-de-piera.com/conectar-a-una-base-de-datos-postgresql-con-pdo/)